# Magnetic Monopole mass-energy effect into Einstein-Field equations

Tags: general-relativity, mass-energy, magnetic-monopoles

I am just wondering, what is the effect of a magnetic monopole mass-energy term in the Einstein Field Equations. Options I thought: does it induce torsion? Non-metricity? Any other weird effect of magnetic monopoles into the Einstein Theory of gravity?
Extra bonus: is there asymmetric or symmetric curvature due to it?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Maxwell Electrodynamics, the effect is identical to an electric charge. For example, the solution of a charged black hole can also be considered for a black hole containing magnetic charge (it would simply be a "duality rotated" version of the Reissner-Nordstrom solution, to use the jargon that the book by Wald uses).

I'll let other users comment on possible situations due to magnetic monopoles occuring on quantum field theories.